# Need to handle huge state object, Is it a good to go ahead with Zustand

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, zustand

With a lot of state management libraries available, it's becoming hard to choose one. From the articles I have gone through, looks like Zustand is a simple and powerful state management library that avoids unnecessary complexity involved in updating the state and maintaining it.

Just want to cross-check, if it is a good idea to go ahead with it, to handle a huge state object and any best practices to handle it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ? Can you share it with me please, i'm in the exact same position as you 3 months ago :'v